# Why my delegate class doesn't work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

I've 3 classes

- 1° contains only the protocol declaration
- 2° call the delegate method when the save button is pressed
- 3° implement the function declared in the protocol and print "It's Work!" on Log

This is what i would do, but it's not working!!

i tried to insert this code in the secondo class:

```
NSLog(@"Delegate --> %@", self.delegate);
```

and i see this line in output:

```
Delegate --> (null)
```

I don't understand WHY and where i'm wrong!!

**1° Class Code:**

```
/************************——— NewContoDelegate.h —————************************/
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Conto.h"

@protocol NewContoDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
-(void)insertNewConto:(Conto *)conto;

@end
```

second class create a new viewController with a

```
UIBarButtonItem *doneitem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Salva" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(saveContoPressed)];
```

When the button is pressed call delegate method:

```
[self.delegate insertNewConto:newConto];
```

**2° Class Code:**

```
/************************———- NewViewController.h —————************************/

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "NewContoDelegate.h"
#import "Conto.h"



@interface NewViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, NewContoDelegate>{
…
…

   __weak id <NewContoDelegate> _delegate;

}

- (void)saveContoPressed;


@property (nonatomic, weak) id <NewContoDelegate> delegate;


@end

/************************———- NewViewController.m —————************************/
#import "NewViewController.h"
#import "Conto.h"

@interface NewViewController ()
@end

@implementation NewViewController

@synthesize delegate = _delegate;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        //self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

        …
    …
    …


        UIBarButtonItem *doneitem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Salva" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(saveContoPressed)];


        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=doneitem;


    }
    return self;
}

- (void)saveContoPressed
{
        if(condition){
        … something …

    } else {

                Conto *newConto = [[Conto alloc] init];

                [self.delegate insertNewConto:newConto];
           } 
}
```

The last class implements the insertNewConto function

**3° Class Code:**

```
/************************———- ListViewController.h —————************************/

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "NewContoDelegate.h"
#import "Conto.h"


@interface ListViewController : UIViewController  <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NewContoDelegate> {

}

@end

/************************———- ListViewController.m —————************************/

#import "ListViewController.h"

@interface ListViewController ()
@end

@implementation ListViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        // Custom initialization
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    …
        …


    }
    return self;
}

-(void)insertNewConto:(Conto *)conto {

    NSLog(@“It’s Work! :) ”);


}
```

## **SOLUTION**

Set delegate in AppDelegate class:

```
newViewController.delegate = listViewController;
```

Comment: I don't see, where you set the delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the delegate like this

```
self.listViewController = [[ListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
self.delegate = self.listViewController;
```

in your init. And somebody has to have a strong reference to the delegate instance.

Comment: I must insert this line in the second class, that one have the property delegate?? because in that class i have not an instance of ListViewController. If i try to create it i have an other object ListViewController, different from the first. The new object is not a view displayed of the application.

Comment: Sorry, but i really don't understand why my delegate class don't work! I made a similar app with a guide and the delegate class work with out problems. The delegate class is the same but in my app it does not work. :( :(

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like your not setting the ListViewController as the delegate of your NewContoDelegate.

Your accept the protocol but never set the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

**I UNDERSTAND!!!!!**

As you told me I forgot to set delegate, but i haven't realized that: I must set delegate in the **AppDelegate** class!!! Thanks for the answers!!

I insert this line in AppDelegate:

```
newViewController.delegate = listViewController;
```